# Prove one to one and onto of a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

[image: This is the question]

I have no idea how to proceed this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's causing you problems with writing the matrix of $T$? Hint: you need to look at $T(1+t), T(1-t), T(t^2)$...

Comment: Do you know the definition of one-to-one and onto maps?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $T:V \to W$ is a linear transformation, and that $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and $\mathcal{C} = \{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ are bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively.  Then the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is
$$
A_T = [T]_{\mathcal B \to \mathcal C} =
\pmatrix{
|&|&|\\
[T(v_1)]_\mathcal{C} & 
[T(v_2)]_\mathcal{C} & 
[T(v_3)]_\mathcal{C}\\
|&|&|
}
$$
So, for this example, we have $v_1 = 1+t$, so that
$$
\begin{align}
T(v_1) &= T(1+t) = 
\pmatrix{
1+1&1+0\\1+0 & 1-1} = 
\pmatrix{2&1\\1&0} 
\\& =
2 \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + 1 \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + 0 \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
= \pmatrix{2\\1\\0}_\mathcal{C}
\end{align}
$$
So, our matrix will be
$$
A_T = [T]_{\mathcal B \to \mathcal C} = 
\pmatrix{
2&|&|\\
1 & 
[T(1-t)]_\mathcal{C} & 
[T(t^2)]_\mathcal{C}\\
0&|&|
}
$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Oh I get it . Thanks for the instruction! But can you show me how to prove T is one-to-one and onto?

Comment: Once you find the matrix $A_T$, find the null-space of the transformation.  If the null-space is trivial (that is, the only vector in the null-space is the $0$ vector), then $T$ must be both one to one and onto.  Otherwise, $T$ is neither.

Comment: In this case, you should find that the transformation is neither one-to-one nor onto.